# How do you keep your text from being copied?

Tags: css, web-development

In a website, how do you keep your text from being highlighted and copied using only css?

Comment: If you want to make it technologically difficult for your text to be copied, don't put it on the world wide web.

Comment: Why would you even want to do it with only CSS?

Comment: @ṧнʊß Cool name.  It's a hypothetical question, big guy.  It saves a lot of work, and it's pretty damned effective.  I sat about 10 of my friends down, and they spent hours between them trying to figure it out.  None of them realized that they were highlighting text the entire time.

Comment: ok, but if someone *really* wanted to highlight some of your text, then they (or at least *I* would), start looking at your html and css (inspect element ;)

Comment: This question should not be closed as "too broad", but deserves to be closed as "off-topic". However, it is very interesting and the answer is quite nice. It would fit well in Stack Overflow. (what is off-topic is requesting a solution with CSS)

Comment: You guys are ridiculous.  This question is wildly specific, and it has more solutions than just one.  Giving it a -2 is kind of BS when you have commenters who are not satisfied with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
::selection {
/* background: transparent; */
}
```

Comment: ^^ So funny, but it works.

Comment: This shouldn't keep it from being copied.

Comment: @VirtualDXS Sure it will.  It creates the illusion.  It's like putting an ADT sign on your house and no actual security system. :D